# Can't pass file handle and lock to a process with multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool()` to launch a bunch of processes, where each process writes to the same file (using a lock).

Each process gets assigned a "task", which is just a tuple of arguments.

One of the arguments is the file handle, and another argument is the lock.

But Python doesn't like me passing neither the file handle nor the lock.

(I **can** do it *without* using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, when calling simply `multiprocessing.Process`.)

Example.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random

def thr_work00(args):
  arg0 = args[0]
  arg1 = args[1]
  arg2 = args[2]
  arg3 = args[3]
  arg4 = args[4]
  s = random.random()/10
  time.sleep(s)
  print(f'\x1b[92m{arg0} \x1b[32m{s:.3f}\x1b[0m')
  return args

o_file = open('test.txt','w')
o_lock = mp.Lock()

tasks = [
  [0, 0,1, o_file,o_lock],
  [1, 2,3, o_file,o_lock],
  [2, 4,5, o_file,o_lock],
  [3, 6,7, o_file,o_lock],
]

with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
  results = pool.map(thr_work00, tasks)
  for res in results:
    print(res)
```

When passing the file I get: `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object` .

When passing the lock I get: `RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`.

How can I get around this?

---

Edit.

So I wonder if this is okay (it seems to be working). The only thing I care about is that each `write` itself is atomic, but it doesn't matter in which order the writes are done.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import os

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
def thr_work00(args):
  arg0 = args[0]
  arg1 = args[1]
  s = random.random()/10
  time.sleep(s)
  txt = 1004*str(arg0)
  with open('test.txt','a') as o_file:
    o_file.write(f'{txt}\n')
  print(f'\x1b[92m{arg0} \x1b[32m{s:.3f}\x1b[0m')
  return args

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
os.remove('test.txt')

tasks = [
  [0, 0xf0],
  [1, 0xf1],
  [2, 0xf2],
  [3, 0xf3],
  [4, 0xf4],
  [5, 0xf5],
  [6, 0xf6],
  [7, 0xf7],
]

with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
  results = pool.map(thr_work00, tasks)
  for res in results:
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both locks and open file descriptors, you should be sharing these through process inheritance, rather than trying to pass them as parameters. A child process inherits all the open file descriptors from its parent, so you can write your code like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random


def thr_work00(args):
    global o_lock, o_file

    s = random.randint(0, 5)
    with o_lock:
        time.sleep(s)
        print(f"\x1b[92m{args[0]} \x1b[32m{s}\x1b[0m")
        o_file.write(f"{args[0]} {s}\n")
        o_file.flush()
    return args


with open("test.txt", "w") as o_file:
    o_lock = mp.Lock()

    tasks = [
        [0, 0, 1],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 5],
        [3, 6, 7],
    ]

    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(thr_work00, tasks)
        for res in results:
            print(res)
```

---

Alternately, instead  of writing  to the file in your worker, just
perform the writes in the main thread as you gather the results. This
eliminates the need for the lock because you no longer need to worry
about multiple processes writing to the same file...

...or, if you need the writes to happen "live", rather than at the end, deliver them to a dedicated writer thread using a `Queue`.

---

Here's one example of using a Queue to pass results to a dedicate
writer:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random

resultq = mp.Queue()


def thr_work00(args):
    global resultq
    s = random.randint(0, 5)
    print(f"\x1b[92m{args[0]} \x1b[32m{s}\x1b[0m")
    time.sleep(s)
    resultq.put((args[0], s))
    return args


def thr_writer():
    global resultq
    print('writer start')
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as fd:
        while True:
            item = resultq.get()
            if item is None:
                break
            fd.write(f'{item[0]}: {item[1]}\n')
    print('writer exit')


with open("test.txt", "w") as o_file:
    o_lock = mp.Lock()

    writer = mp.Process(target=thr_writer)
    writer.start()

    tasks = [
        [0, 0, 1],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 5],
        [3, 6, 7],
    ]

    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(thr_work00, tasks)
        for res in results:
            print(res)

    resultq.put(None)
    writer.join()
```

Comment: Yup, I do need the writes to happen "live" (because the whole thing takes a long time, and the idea of having each process writing to a file as to save partial progress). If you can elaborate on the `Queue` idea...

Comment: I've added an example that uses a `Queue` and a dedicated writer.

Comment: Does this use of `global` work for "passing" *any* Python object to a process? Or only for specific ones?

Comment: This only works for things that are implemented on top of primitives that can be inherited between processes, such as file descriptors. It won't work for things that are strictly in-memory constructs, like most Python data structures...but see the documentation on [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to create objects that *are* shareable between processes.

Comment: This also only works with linux or OSX when using "fork" rather than "spawn"